# How can I combine column data into one row?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet of product data and I need to combine the filenames of the images into one row for importing reasons.

[image]

I basically need it to look like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to automate this all the way down, possibly by skipping every blank cell?

Comment: You might be looking for a pivot table

Comment: @norbertvannobelen That's what I thought too but I can't get it to work right

Comment: Is the [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027) function not an option? (I'm thinking it isn't if you have thousands of rows).

Comment: @bigben I tried that and it will work but I have about 2,500 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) like this might work for you. This will copy blocks of text in a column and transpose them starting in the first row of each block and one column to the right.

```
Sub TransposeFilenames()
    Dim lRow As Long, fRow As Long, col As Long
    Dim copyRng As Range

    fRow = 2 ' First row with data, change as needed
    col = 3 ' Column with filenames, change as needed

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row  

        Do
            Set copyRng = .Range(.Cells(fRow, col), .Cells(fRow, col).End(xlDown))
            copyRng.Copy
            copyRng.Cells(1).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

            fRow = copyRng.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
        Loop While fRow < lRow

    End With
End Sub
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked for about 50% of my data. There is an error where if the ID only has one filename, it combines the next ID's filename into it's own. This was a great start for me and has definitely worked.

Answer (score 0):

## Here's a simple way to do it with Excel formulas:

**If your data is laid out like this:**

```
    A   B      C     
  +---+---+---------+
1 |...|...|Filename |
2 |...|...|filename1|
3 |...|...|filename2|
4 |...|...|filename3|
5 |...|...|filename4|
6 |...|...|filename5|
7 |...|...|         |
8 |...|...|filename1|
9 |...|...|filename2|
10|...|...|filename3|
11|...|...|filename4|
12|...|...|filename5|
13|...|...|         |
```

**Then put this formula in `D2` and drag-fill across to `H2` and down:**

```
=IF(OR($C2="",$C2 = "Filename"),OFFSET($C2,COLUMN(A1),0),"")
```

**Your result should look like this:**

```
    A   B      C         D        E         F          G         H
  +---+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
1 |...|...|Filename |         |         |         |         |         |
2 |...|...|filename1|filename1|filename2|filename3|filename4|filename5|
3 |...|...|filename2|         |         |         |         |         |
4 |...|...|filename3|         |         |         |         |         |
5 |...|...|filename4|         |         |         |         |         |
6 |...|...|filename5|         |         |         |         |         |
7 |...|...|         |         |         |         |         |         |
8 |...|...|filename1|filename1|filename2|filename3|filename4|filename5|
9 |...|...|filename2|         |         |         |         |         |
10|...|...|filename3|         |         |         |         |         |
11|...|...|filename4|         |         |         |         |         |
12|...|...|filename5|         |         |         |         |         |
13|...|...|         |         |         |         |         |         |
```